# Xbox Controller right stick, wrong output

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox360

apparently I'm not getting any answers to my question the unity Forum, so I'll try it here.
I'm trying to get my xbox Controller to work correctly, the left stick and every Buttons works accordingly. But, the left stick doesn't. When not using the left stick it Outputs -1 when it should be 0, when I press it to the left it still Outputs -1, but that's ok and when I press it to the right it Outputs 1. My Problem is that I don't know how to fix it to Output 0 when stationary.

I already checked alot of threads to this Topic and the unity documentation, but those don't help at all.

My Controller is not broken.

Comment: have you tried increasing the dead value of the axis in the Input Manager? can you share the configuration of a working left stick axis and a broken right stick axis?

Comment: I'm not home currenty but I can provide you a screenshot of the brocken right axis, but the left stick axis are configured default as Horizontal and Vertical by Unity. Here is the screen of the right axis: http://imgur.com/a/e8moR I also tried chaning the dead value and the sensitivity, but that didn't change anything. Also I'm not using these axis names in any script, except for log outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. It turns out Unity does not handle well DualShock 4 controllers, or multiple controllers attached, or the combination of these two. The cause of the problem for me was that I had a DualShock 4 wireless reciever plugged in beside my Xbox 360 controller. Removing it solved it for me. ¯_(ツ)_/¯